# Phone solution for virtual company

Tags: telephone

I am looking for recommendations/links for a service that can give/assign me a phone number, have a recorded messages played when someone calls such as "press 1 for ..., press 2 for yyy etc" and then allow the caller to leave a message that is then emailed to the owner of the particular voicemail box.

Google voice works for 1 mailbox only, but something like that with multiple mailboxes and multiple email addresses would be great.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My company has been using [VirtualPBX](http://www.virtualpbx.com) for this kind of thing for about 5 years now and we like it. They're starting to get into VoIP-based offerings, too. (I find it amusing when a Customer talks about calling me on my "office number"... heh heh...)